# How can I add a computer to a local AD?

Tags: domain, active-directory

I have AD running on a box in my network, its setup with foo.local AD (locally). Im now trying to add another computer (running win7 ult) but when I try to add the computer to domain it shows an error telling me it cant be contacted.

I know the AD servers computername, its IP and the domain i set up (foo.local), what do i put in the Domain field? Are there any ports or so I need to open?

[image]

Comment: Is foo.local not your domain name?

Comment: it is, but where does my win7 ulti look for it? besides being on the same network they do not know each other. in fact, the win7ulti is a VM running on the win2k12 box that runs the ad

Comment: use win2k12 box's ip address as DNS server on win7's network properties and see if it helps

Comment: Works as a charm dusan.bajic! Add it and all accept it!

Answer (score 1):

Use win2k12 box's ip address as DNS server on win7's network properties and see if it helps. After that please read at least [SOME](https://www.google.com/#q=active+directory+guide) documentation about active directory.

Comment: This ^^ Also, if you are running DHCP on your AD box you can use it to set the DNS addresses when your initially given your IP address.